# Manipulate graphics within an R package (eRm)

Tags: r

I am using the eRm package to run the dichotomous Rasch model. My problem is that I can not manipulate the length of the x axis on the person-item map.

The description for the plotPImap command says to use xrange= to specify the range, but when I do so, I get the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Here is my code:

```
Model2 <- RM(EBL_MC)
plotPImap(Model2, xrange=c(-5:5), latdim = "Writing Achievement", main="Person-Item Map (EBL)")
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, since you haven't provided a reproducible example, but generally when functions in R ask for an axis range argument, they are looking for only two values, the low and high. Try `xrange = c(-5,5)`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! (and I'll try to include data in future posts so that they are reproducible)

Comment: @user1541682 No problem, glad it helped! Since you're new here, I thought I'd mention that if an answer happens to solve your problem, it's customary to click the check mark next to it. This increases the value of the question (and the site) to others by giving a clear indication of what answer actually solved your problem. But selecting a answer like this is always your choice alone, and you are always free to not do so.